# Webstorm not accepting Homebrew Git 2.27.0

Tags: git, homebrew, macos-catalina

Webstrom 2020.1 is not accepting the latest git version 2.27.0 installed via Homebrew. When I tried to provide the brew installed git path - `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.27.0/bin/git` in the preferences panel, it says 'Git is not installed'. What could be the problem?

PFB the permissions on the folder 
[folder permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2AX.png)

[Webstrom Git Preference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJXHi.png)

I do have Brew in the path, PFB the list of git installed in my system [Git installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ8W8.png), What I cannot understand is when we give a git path in Webstrom preferences, the assumption is it should use the specified Git installation, which is not happening.

Comment: Assuming brew is in your path, have you tried providing simply `git` without a full path?

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/git`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Intellij 2019.3 Ultimate.

And this is my local git setup (I just upgraded from `2.26.2` to `2.27.0`):

```
$ ls -al $(which git)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rchen  staff  28 Jul  5 23:56 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.27.0/bin/git
```

Both [`/usr/local/bin/git`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGf1h.png) (auto-detected by Intellij) and [`/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.27.0/bin/git`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfbs.png) work for me. Here is the [successful test snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8F0c.png).